# How to test for $null array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, null

I'm using an array variable in PowerShell 2.0.  If it does not have a value, it will be $null, which I can test for successfully:

```
PS C:\> [array]$foo = $null
PS C:\> $foo -eq $null
True
```

But when I give it a value, the test for $null does not return anything:

```
PS C:\> [array]$foo = @("bar")
PS C:\> $foo -eq $null
PS C:\>
```

How can "-eq $null" give no results?  It's either $null or it's not.

What is the correct way to determine if an array is populated vs. $null?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

It's an array, so you're looking for Count to test for contents.

I'd recommend

```
$foo.count -gt 0
```

The "why" of this is related to how PSH handles comparison of collection objects

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work when `[array]$foo = $null`. Instead of 0, `$foo.count` returns nothing.

Comment: but (nothing -gt 0 == FALSE), which is why I suggested using that operator.  If you check that you'll have a true/false, regardless of nullness

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes that is shorter and somewhat more intuitive than having to use the `else` block of an `if ($foo -eq $null)` statement. Interesting that when `[array]$foo = $null`, `$foo.count -eq 0` is False, but `$foo.count -lt 0` is True. I guess $null is less than 0. Wonder if that is documented somewhere?

Comment: Well an array is a construct, even when empty .. and the count() is on the construct object, not its contents, so the minute you create the array it has a count property

Comment: Just noting that `$null.count -lt 0` is True, while `$null.count -gt 0` is False.  If that's the guaranteed result, then `$foo.count -lt 0` could be used to check for $null, e.g when I want to do something if the array hasn't been created.  Although in that case, the `if ($foo -eq $null`) might be more readable.

Comment: If you really wanna hurt your head, powershell will tell you that $null -lt 0 == TRUE, but $null -lt -1 == FALSE. so -1 < null < 0

Comment: @Taylor $foo.count returns empty in case the array has only one value

Comment: This approach fails if you have Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

Answer (score 52):

You can reorder the operands:

```
$null -eq $foo
```

Note that `-eq` in PowerShell is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: Cool. Hadn't thought of that. So the -eq only scans a collection for values if the collection is to the _left_ of the -eq.

Comment: @Mark: Indeed. See `help about_Comparison_Operators` where this is described.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Joey This works in even in case array has one value or no value !

Comment: This didn't work for me, $foo = @()

Answer (score 23):

```
if($foo -eq $null) { "yes" } else { "no" }

help about_comparison_operators
```

displays help and includes this text:

> All comparison operators except the
>   containment operators (-contains,
>   -notcontains) and type operators (-is, -isnot) return a Boolean value when the input to the operator (the value
>   on the left side of the operator) is a
>   single value (a scalar). **When the
>   input is a collection of values**, the
>   containment operators and the type
>   operators return any matching values.
>   If there are no matches in a
>   collection, these operators do not
>   return anything. The containment
>   operators and type operators always
>   return a Boolean value.

Comment: Yeah I was missing the idea that -eq scans a non-empty collection for matching values and returns the VALUE, not True or False. Very confusing especially if the collection contains empty strings. If `[array]$foo=@("")`, your if statement works, but its inverse does not: `if($foo -ne $null) { "no" } else { "yes" }` returns "yes". Since the main thing I want to do is test for NOT null (i.e. there are elements to work on), that means I have to use `if($foo -eq $null) { # Do nothing } else { #Do something }`.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to figure out why this seemed to return no answer:  `$a = @();  $a -eq $null`

Comment: In PowerShell, $null should be at the left side of the comparison.

Answer (score 9):

If your solution requires returning 0 instead of true/false, I've found this to be useful:

```
PS C:\> [array]$foo = $null
PS C:\> ($foo | Measure-Object).Count
0
```

This operation is different from the count property of the array, because `Measure-Object` is counting objects. Since there are none, it will return 0.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers address the main thrust of the question, but just to comment on this part...

> ```
> PS C:\> [array]$foo = @("bar")
> PS C:\> $foo -eq $null
> PS C:\>
> ```
>
> How can "-eq $null" give no results? It's either $null or it's not.

It's confusing at first, but that *is* giving you the result of `$foo -eq $null`, it's just that the result has no displayable representation.

Since `$foo` holds an array, `$foo -eq $null` means "return an array containing the elements of `$foo` that are equal to `$null`".  Are there any elements of `$foo` that are equal to `$null`?  No, so `$foo -eq $null` should return an empty array.  That's exactly what it does, the problem is that when an empty array is displayed at the console you see...nothing...

```
PS> @()
PS>
```

The array is still there, even if you can't see its elements...

```
PS> @().GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS> @().Length
0
```

We can use similar commands to confirm that `$foo -eq $null` *is* returning an array that we're not able to "see"...

```
PS> $foo -eq $null
PS> ($foo -eq $null).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS> ($foo -eq $null).Length
0
PS> ($foo -eq $null).GetValue(0)
Exception calling "GetValue" with "1" argument(s): "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
At line:1 char:1
+ ($foo -eq $null).GetValue(0)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IndexOutOfRangeException
```

Note that I am calling the [`Array.GetValue` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.getvalue) instead of using the indexer (i.e. `($foo -eq $null)[0]`) because the latter returns `$null` for invalid indices and there's no way to distinguish them from a valid index that happens to contain `$null`.

We see similar behavior if we test for `$null` in/against an array that contains `$null` elements...

```
PS> $bar = @($null)
PS> $bar -eq $null
PS> ($bar -eq $null).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS> ($bar -eq $null).Length
1
PS> ($bar -eq $null).GetValue(0)
PS> $null -eq ($bar -eq $null).GetValue(0)
True
PS> ($bar -eq $null).GetValue(0) -eq $null
True
PS> ($bar -eq $null).GetValue(1)
Exception calling "GetValue" with "1" argument(s): "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
At line:1 char:1
+ ($bar -eq $null).GetValue(1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IndexOutOfRangeException
```

In this case, `$bar -eq $null` returns an array containing one element, `$null`, which has no visual representation at the console...

```
PS> @($null)
PS> @($null).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS> @($null).Length
1
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I used this to do a similar thing with Pester:
# If the variable is an empty array.
$value = @()
$value.GetType().BaseType.ToString() | Should -Be 'System.Array'
# If the variable is $null.
$value = $null
{ $value.GetType().BaseType.ToString() } | Should -Throw

Answer (score 3):

How do you want things to behave?

If you want arrays with no elements to be treated the same as unassigned arrays, use:

```
[array]$foo = @() #example where we'd want TRUE to be returned
@($foo).Count -eq 0
```

If you want a blank array to be seen as having a value (albeit an empty one), use:

```
[array]$foo = @() #example where we'd want FALSE to be returned
$foo.PSObject -eq $null
```

If you want an array which is populated with only null values to be treated as null:

```
[array]$foo = $null,$null
@($foo | ?{$_.PSObject}).Count -eq 0
```

NB: In the above I use `$_.PSObject` over `$_` to avoid `[bool]$false`, `[int]0`, `[string]''`, etc from being filtered out; since here we're focussed solely on nulls.

Comment: Those are helpful thoughts about how to initialize arrays for various behaviors, but this doesn't answer the original question, "What is the correct way to determine if an array is populated vs. $null?" Perhaps that should be amended to add, "even if I don't know how the array was initialized?"

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for switch.  It will *never run* with a null array, for example as the output of an empty directory.

```
switch ( $null ) { default { 'yes' } }
yes

switch ( @() ) { default { 'yes' } }  # no output

mkdir foo
switch ( dir foo ) { default { 'yes' } }  # no output
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all of these answers work for me.  I ended up doing this, treating it like a boolean.

```
$foo = @()
if (! $foo) { 'empty array' }

empty array
```

Actually, I came across an arraylist inside an object.

```
[pscustomobject]@{config = [Collections.ArrayList]@()} | ? { ! $_.config }

config
------
{}
```